# add custom get parameter to woocomerce thanks you page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need add custom get parameter to woocomerce thanks you page if order_amount is more that 50$. I need it for tracking purpose. Maybe someone have function for it?
standard page link:

> https://somesite.com/checkout/order-received/1111110/?key=wc_order_C5OOjXBZyAdqx

and with order amount parametr

> https://somesite.com/checkout/order-received/1111110/?key=wc_order_C5OOjXBZyAdqx&order_amount=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_return_url', 'wc_override_thankyou_url', 10, 2 );
function wc_override_thankyou_url( $url, $order ){

    if( $order->get_total() >= 50 ){
        $url = $url . '&order_amount=50';
    }

    return $url;
}
```